# .NET Object Database Options?

Tags: object-oriented-database

Since Versant has just announced that they will be dropping .NET support for their object databases (and we just so happen to be mid-development with this product), we're looking for an alternative.

Our development is of moderate size and requires support for concurrent queries and high availability.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options we explored:

- [Eloquera](http://www.eloquera.com/)
- [NDatabase](http://ndatabase.codeplex.com/)
- [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/)
- [Siaqodb](http://siaqodb.com/)
- [Joob](http://www.joobworld.com/)

We leaned towards settling on Joob, but haven't made any decisions yet.

Comment: Can you tell us more since this is for a long time ago. What did you choose ?

Comment: @Mahdi We ended up putting the project on hold.  We're starting up again later this year and decided to use entity framework instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try Eloquera database (native .NET object database)
www.eloquera.com

Comment: Thanks, +1 for answering.  We had a phone conversation with Eloquera but they weren't a good fit for our development.  It sounds like they are geared more toward single-user/embedded applications such as, say, an iPhone app.